# building a function that takes 2d array and prints average in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, average

I need a way to build a function that takes a 2d array and prints the average , using numpy.

how do I do that?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is it a numpy array?
If so, you could just use

```
arr.mean()
```

if it is just a nested list, you could turn in into numpy array first

```
np_arr = np.array(arr)
np_arr.mean()
```